# How to call documentation which exists but is very limited?

Tags: word-choice

If I use deepl to translate from my native language to english,
I get this: "the documentation is thin".

But I am unsure if **thin** is the matching term.

How to call documentation which covers only 20% and 80% are missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the word [**sparse**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sparse):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : of few and scattered elements
>   *especially* : not thickly grown or settled

Note that the *especially* part of the definition refers to the use of the word in the context of geography (such as countryside). In the context of documentation, or any production of labour, you can ignore that sense—unless you want to consider it metaphorically.

---

An alternative is [*minimal*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/minimal), depending on exactly what you're trying to convey. But unless what is written is enough to get by, it sounds to me like 20% isn't actually sufficient.

Comment: Jason suggested **sparse**, not **spare**.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, "sparse" fits. I think "minimal" is something different. For me "minimal" is a positive adjective: All redundancy was removed. (@KateBunting I deleted/recreated my old comment)

Comment: I accepted this answer. Nevertheless alternatives are welcome. Just create a second answer. Thank youi.